# Using the epsilon- N definition of the limit verify that:

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} = \frac{1}{3}$

Here is what I have so far:

$\mathrm{x}_\mathrm{n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}},$ $a=\frac{1}{3}$

$ \forall{\epsilon}$ $\exists{\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{\epsilon}}$ $|$ $\forall{n}\in{\mathbb{N}}$ $n>\mathrm{N}_\mathrm{\epsilon} \Rightarrow|\mathrm{x}_\mathrm{n}-a|<\epsilon$

$|\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}}-\frac{1}{3}|\Rightarrow$

Then I applied the got a common denominator and applied the algebraic formula $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ and ended up with the following but I cannot see how I should simplify it any further before I analyze to verify the inequality is less than epsilon. Here is where I am stuck in the simplification:
$$|\frac{4n+3}{9n\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}+3(9n^2+4n+3)}|$$

Comment: Show your work, please!

Comment: Take a look at [this advice for improving your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), particularly the heading entitled "Provide Context".

Comment: Hint: You don't need to find the smallest $N$.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that the task is about showing that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} = \frac{1}{3} $$

Here's one way:

It holds that $\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2\left(9+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}\right)}} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}{\sqrt{9+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}}} $

Since $n \ge 1$ it holds that

$ \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}{\sqrt{9+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}}}  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{9+\frac{4}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}}$

which converges $\to \frac{1}{3}$ for $n \to \infty$

**Edit:**

This is another approach using $\varepsilon$ kriteria:

We want to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0 $ there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \vert \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} -\frac{1}{3} \vert < \varepsilon $$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

It holds that $ \vert \frac{1}{2n} \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $

now begin with

$$ \left\vert \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} -\frac{1}{3} \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{3n -\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}}{3\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}} \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{9n^2-(9n^2+4n+3)}{3\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}(3n+\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3})} \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{-4n-3}{9n\sqrt{9n^2+4n+3}+3(9n^2+4n+3)} \right\vert < \left\vert \frac{-4n-3}{9n^2} \right\vert = \vert -1 \vert \left\vert\frac{4n+3}{9n^2} \right\vert = \left\vert\frac{4n+3}{9n^2} \right\vert $$

Now making use of the triangle inequality leads to

$$\left\vert\frac{4n+3}{9n^2} \right\vert \le \left\vert\frac{4n}{9n^2} \right\vert + \left\vert\frac{3}{9n^2} \right\vert \le \left\vert\frac{4}{9n} \right\vert + \left\vert\frac{3}{9n} \right\vert < \left\vert\frac{1}{2n} \right\vert + \left\vert\frac{1}{2n} \right\vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon  $$

I'm sure there are better or at least more elegant solutions but i think it suffices the task.

Comment: I believe that would be the method used to solve this problem in a calculus course and an acceptable answer for that. Although I do not believe it will  be an acceptable solution for real analysis.

Comment: @kymel102011 i apologize. I edited my answer and added another approach. You might want to take a look at it.